# Magento2: How to change the content in the block

Tags: magento2

I can not find any way to change the text in this block when logging in.
[image]

does anyone know how I can change this content?

Comment: Please template hints on in the admin panel then you can display where it is this block

Comment: I fount this block in: app/design/template/template/magento-customer/newcustomer.phtml and I have change text here. But now: just now how do I display the translated  this text for 2 store view ?

Comment: You can translate it by translation Csv for multiple store. No need to change in phtml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite this file:

/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/newcustomer.phtml

Comment: Sanne, in this file I have another text: <p><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Creating an account has many benefits: check out faster, keep more than one address, track orders and more.')) ?></p>

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the current store id and the store name in block file
 (using ObjectManager) like below :

```
     $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        
     $storeManager  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
     $storeID       = $storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId(); 
     $storeName     = $storeManager->getStore()->getName();
```

you can use this $storeID according to your condition :

```
      if ($storeID = '1')
     {
       // your text
      }else if ($storeID = '2'){
   // Your other text
   }
```

Comment: Poorly-written and completely irrelevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below example for multiple store, You can changed text for all store by translation CSV file with out changing any phtml file.

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourThem/i18n/en_US.csv //First store local code
```

> "Creating an account has many benefits: check out faster, keep more
>   than one address, track orders and more.","Your custom text for here
>   for Store-1"

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourThem/i18n/en_GB.csv //Second  store local code
```

> "Creating an account has many benefits: check out faster, keep more
>   than one address, track orders and more.","Your custom text for here
>   for Store-2"

Run below commands and check

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
```